# Connect to windows server from node js

Tags: node.js, excel, windows-server

I'm not very experienced in programming and have a problem that I'm finding hard do solve.

I have a web app that is on a ubuntu server, that is running on node js. That web app creates an excel file on the back-end that is to be read by another excel file and execute a vba that gives as results in a software that only runs on windows.

I tried the software on a windows server and it seems to run, so no problems there.

My question is: how do I make my web app excel file be stored in the windows server and how do I call the files on that server to run from node js?

Can anyone please share some resources on where I can explore this subject please?

Thanks in advance,

Ana

Comment: I think your best bet here is to host your NodeJS web-app (back-end part at least) on your Windows Server. That way, you share the same file-system and the software that only runs on Windows can be spawned directly by your back-end. Otherwise, you'll have to implement another back-end app on the Windows server that queries the Ubuntu back-end for the file and send back the processed file (or store the file in a database rather than a file-system, but that only moves the problem since you will still have to query the database from the Windows server).

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals thanks for your reply. I've been searching about that as well but haven't find a good resource to be able to do it for my experience level. I'll be looking further into it. If you know any resource that could be of help and won't mind sharing I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is what I advised the OP to do in the comments, only longer and with more explanation.

- First, install NodeJS on your Windows server. You can do it by either installing it from the official [Downloads](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) page from NodeJS, or use a version manager such as `nvm`, with a [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-windows) on how to do it that way. This step is up to you.
- Host your **back-end part** (the one that creates the excel part) on the Windows server. That way, the file will be stored in the same filesystem the "software that runs only on Windows" is on.
- The problem now is determining if there is any way to run the "software" via command line. Since I don't know the software name, I can't look that up but if it can, you'll have to check [child processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) via NodeJS.
- Now, if this software has no way to be run via command line, and if they didn't publish any sort of programming interface (what is called API in the real definition of the term), chances are that you will not be able to achieve what you want to.

If you want me to clarify or explain more on some points, please let me know in the comments so I can edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks for a more detailed answer. The vba in the excel calls the software, so it's good on that part. I'll try to run node on the windows server and will give feedback on how it went. Thank you